# Downloading file with Python results in only 4.1kB

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc

I'm using simple code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mysite.com/getfile/4355")
output = open('myfile.zip','wb')
output.write(response.read())
output.close()
```

The web-server is IIS + ASP.NET MVC 4
It returns FileResult wrapping a zip-file with "application/octet-stream" content-type.

The problem is that downloaded zip file is broken - only 4.1kB size, where it must be 24kB. When I type the url adress in web-browser directly - it downloads and opens fine.

Could you please, suggest, what's wrong with my Python code?

**Edit**

Tried two other ways - same result.

```
    import urllib
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, targetFile)

    h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
    response, content = h.request(url)
    with open(targetFile, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

That was a stupid question, but anyway: I had [Authorize] attribute on my Controller so that no anonymous requests could be done.

Removing it just allowed me to download the file.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into python 'requests' module. You can pip install it. Example code is:

```
>>>import requests
>>>req_obj = requests.get("http://www.myexample.com/myfile.zip")
>>>print len(req_obj)
203456
```

More information about the API can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)...

Answer (score 0):

For future references, in py3k you will have to only use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(the_url, the_filename)` to download a file like:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.example.com/the-file.zip'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'filename.zip')
```